# WebGrid checkbox MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I have a view model which has a list of objects.

Binding the list to the WebGrid is fine and displays all data correctly.

The objects have a boolean value I'd like the user to change by selecting a checkbox displayed with each record in a WebGrid. When the user checks/unchecks various checkboxes then clicks an update button, I want to be able to save the changes on the objects.

The updating is proving a right "pain in the A..." with MVC and Razor.

How can I send these changes back to the controller?
Can someone please advise?
Any samples?

**Update:**

I have been able to pass the whole form back to the Controller after giving each checkbox a name and ID. The value is set to the item.Id and is only found in the form's attributes if the checkbox was actually checked.

So in the Controller, I do this:

```
public ActionResult Assign(FormCollection form)
{
    var ch = form.GetValues("itemChk");
    foreach (var id in ch)
    {
      //...Get object using id
      //...Call your method
    }
    return View();
}
```

ch is a string array of the item.Ids of only those checkboxes that were checked.
By returning the item.Id as a value of a checked checkbox, I can assign/set that value on the item itself and save/update it.

Next to try get ALL checkboxes returned with values. Also to at text box to each row in the WebGrid and try something similar to handle the return values.

Here's [the link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/273164/mvc3-checkbox-checked-rows-in-the-web-grid) that got me going down this track.

Comment: Why do you want all checkboxes to be returned with values? What values? Also, what is stopping you adding a textbox? You do that in the same way as you added the checkbox.

Comment: Please give your question a _meaningful_ title. Don't list _tags_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json ajax call to pass the FormCollection to the controller

```
$('#btnClick').click(function (event) {
    var form = $("#fmSearch").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Assign',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: form,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: OnError
    });
});
```

Please note: do not add "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" because no any json content.

fmSearch is the id of Html.BeginForm(), you can write them as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "fmSearch" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
}
```

Last, add `[HttpPost]` above your action and replace ActionResult with JsonResult.